# Travel protection bag OK at airport?

Tags: luggage, legal

I have a travel protection bag in which my whole suitcase fits. It's just a nylon zippered suitcase-size bag with a handle; when the suitcase is in it the whole thing just looks just like a lumpy duffel bag. Someone suggested that the airlines would not like it because

1. the wheels and handle do not stick out, so that baggage handlers can't use them, and
2. it's one more thing to unzip if the customs wants to search my baggage en route.

Are either of these objections valid? As for (1), the hiding of the wheels and handles is one plus for me, because I have had damage to the handles of my suitcases en route. As for (2), I like the bag because I don't lock the zips on the suitcase, so the bag makes sure that things don't accidentally fall out. Yes, I know about the plastic wrapping, but not all airports have it, and you have to pay for it when they do. So, should I use my luggage protection bag?

Comment: What does it matter if the airlines don't like it? I have to put up with lots of things they do that I don't like; I wouldn't have any qualms about doing something that they didn't like.

Answer (score 8):

You should have no problem using the bag.
I have done similarly and I have seen many checked in bags that are not optimal to handle. A very broad range of "objects" are carried as check in baggage - a mere outer bag is far from unusual.

If customs want to look inside your bag then they **will** look inside your bag. The only exception is if you make it so secure that they cannot be bothered spending the effort required to open it. In such cases your bag will not fly and you may not either.

This is my [**Ocean Jumping Bag** approach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23031/how-can-i-minimize-the-weight-of-the-suitcase-of-my-checked-in-luggage/23075#23075) which is my preferred method of carrying more than will fit in my checked-in bag - and which approximates your travel protection bag (but in a rather less pretty way).

Not giving a luggage handler a handle to handle may be a bonus as it may make it harder for them to throw it violently. However, they appear to be quite ingenious in finding ways to damage bags so this may no help you. [I've taken a number of photos of handlers throwing bags into a mobile luggage transporter, and also throwing them some metres onto a ground to aircraft portable conveyer, with the occasional bag falling off the edges part way up and needing to be recovered and re-thrown. A recent video showed handlers working together to use a wall to test and/or modify baggage integrity.]

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the bag-in-bag technique you mention is definitely not forbidden by airlines. On the contrary, airlines often suggest to wrap/bag luggage of unusual shapes or sizes, to avoid problems during baggage-handling procedures. [This is the case of large backpacks for example, whose loose straps might get caught in the conveyor belts.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42005/how-to-check-a-large-backpack) Therefore I would not worry about airlines forbidding this practice. In conclusion, go ahead and use your luggage-protection bag.