# Can I carry more luggage volumes with the same weight

Tags: air-travel, luggage

I'm looking for information about how many items of luggage may I carry.

Normally the airline companies say for example:

> The passenger can carry 2 items of luggage with a total of 30 kg.

If I travel with my partner and she carries more than 30 kg and I don't. Will we be charged for the extra weight?

Is it a problem to carry 3 items that are each 10 kg for example? Will the company charge me for the extra item?

Comment: Luggage allowance is specified per person. Hence following from your example, each passenger can carry *maximum* 2x30kg of luggage. If you travel with your wife, you two will get 2x2x30kg of luggage allowance. So yes, two passengers will be able to carry 3x10kg of luggage on the plane.

Comment: Just to make sure you can call them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the conditions of your fare say 2 pieces of luggage and up to 30kg, it means just that. Depending on the route, you will typically find at least three types of limitations:

- Number of pieces of luggage
- Total weight (spread between all your luggage)
- Weight per piece of luggage
- Size limits

You might be able to pool the total weight between several passengers, but not the weight by piece of luggage (which is mostly there for the health and safety of the workers who have to lift and handle them). And if you want, say, more than two pieces of luggage, when that's what you are allowed to take, you will have to pay extra, even if each of them are not heavy. It's therefore possible that packing your two 10kg pieces together in a bigger suitcase would save money.

Comment: In an other question (http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47048/travel-protection-bag-ok-at-airport ) they mention a bag to go outside a suitcase, this kind of bag can also be helpful to check in two cases with little weight as one heavier one.

Comment: There are also generally size limitations, usually measured in linear inches (h+w+l) on each peice.