# Can I bring a skillet with me as a carry-on item?

Tags: air-travel, uk, luggage, airports, hand-luggage

My suitcases are very small (smaller than the maximum dimensions allowed for carry-on items), so I can't put my skillet inside and check the suitcase. I wonder if it is possible to take the skillet with me as a carry-on item. The skillet has a box.

Oh also, this is for an international flight to the US.

EDIT: Based on the list of forbidden items, it doesn't seem skillets are forbidden...

- Toy or replica guns (plastic or metal).
- Knives with blades more than 6cm.
  Lighter top-up fuel (passengers are allowed to carry one disposable lighter in a clear re-sealable plastic bag).
- Razor blades.
- Scissors - specifically, blades measuring greater than 6cm in length.
- Hypodermic syringes (unless supported by medical evidence).
- Builder's tools.
- Hammers, nails or screw-drivers.
- Darts.
- Sporting bats.
- Billiard, snooker or pool cues.
- Catapults and sling-shots.
- Umbrellas - unless foldable.
- Acid.
- Explosives
- Gas cartridges, or gas cartridge re-fills.
- Paint.
- Lighter fuel.
- Mercury.
- Restraining Items - such as, handcuffs, fishing line or restraining tape.

Comment: [TSA](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/prohibited-items) reports for a cast-iron skillet: check only. What's your originating airport?

Comment: you **can't** check the suitcase or you don't have to? I've seen some bags on the luggage belt that could have been carryon, but were checked. In fact, I've done it myself on more than one occasion.

Comment: I can check the suitcase, but my suitcase is too small to hold the skillet.

Comment: https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_home.aspx

Comment: @phoog: I will go through the security check point in the UK, not in the US (no layover in the US)

Comment: I would not dream of trying to "carry on"  such an item. It certainly COULD be used as a weapon and if any customs officer chose to confiscate it they could do so, and you have zero right of redress. I have had items confiscated which were far less dangerous in reality, if not in theory.  || All you need to check it in is a version of my [**ocean jumping bags**](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23031/how-can-i-minimize-the-weight-of-the-suitcase-of-my-checked-in-luggage/23075#23075) -  a small one in your case :-).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would depend on the security officer that checks you in and the country where your flight originates.

[TSA doesn't allow frying pans](http://www.tsa.gov/data/cib.xml) especially cast iron ones it's check only as evidenced in a [blog from Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/andrewbender/2012/06/11/the-dumbest-things-people-try-to-carry-through-airport-security/).

TSA also has a mobile app now that you can look at.  But since it's a flight originating from another country TSA rules may not apply so originating country's rules will have to be followed.

**Based on additional information**

There is nothing specific regarding skillets for [carry-on luggage in the UK](https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions/overview) so they may allow skillet through but I would still put it into a checked bag or just ship it home.

Comment: I am not sure but I seem to remember something like 'blunt object' not being allowed, as in something that can be used to hit/kill someone. (I have used the UK as well as other EU airports).

Comment: @Willeke Therein lies a problem.  There is no clarification...

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind: Regardless of your country of origin, if you have a connection in the U.S. (say, you're flying from London to New York then connecting to Nashville,) you will go through a TSA checkpoint at the connection. Similarly, regardless of your country of origin, you will go through a TSA checkpoint on your return flight. So, unless you're planning a one-way trip to the U.S. with no connections, TSA rules will indeed apply at some point on your trip.

Comment: @reirab Not necessarily but a good point.

Comment: Not necessarily for which part? I mean, I guess you could leave the U.S. by land or ship, but I was assuming air travel departing from the U.S. for the return. :)

Comment: My connection is in Heathrow. No connection in the US.

Comment: @reirab Some connections between US airports are not served by plane.  So no TSA.

Comment: Ah, Yes, by "connecting," I meant "connecting by plane."

Comment: +1, but I don't get the rationale for wanting to carry a skillet. Checked or carry on it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @GayotFow Stranger things have been known to happen and stranger people have been known to travel...

Comment: @GayotFow: It's a $200 skillet. I don't want to have to replace it!! :-/

Comment: Can't say I would have bought something like this abroad...