# Plastic boxes on easyjet?

Tags: luggage, easyjet

I'm moving house and I need to use easyjet to do it.

I've booked 3 pieces of luggage, and I'm wondering, would a plastic box like this be allowable?

[image]

In the past I've had a good experience with easyjet allowing cardboard boxes; even a TV in a box once.

But I've heard mutterings they balk at this a bit, even if fully taped up so I can ensure it does not open.

Comment: Would you be willing to pack them in "ocean jumping bags" (as per this answer: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/23075/27650 ) The bags do not much for protection but will make airlines accept the luggage.

Comment: Those plastic boxes are often not all that strong.  If it gets dropped, or if heavy stuff is put on top of it in the cargo hold, it may break.

Comment: An obvious point would be to ensure those boxes fit in the diameters given for luggage, but also I wanted to point out that a fabric type suitcase in my experience can fit far more in than one of these boxes because it's more adaptable, and less likely to shatter

Answer (score 1):

While plastic boxes will likely be accepted, well sealed and reinforced with tape on all edges, it is up to the agent handling checking in for the final decision.

If you pack the boxes in bag, and those can be really cheap, it is much less likely that they will be rejected.
And such a bag will protect your box and keep the contents of the box together in case a box does break.

If you had not already bought the boxes I would have advised you not to buy them but go for duffel type bags or suitcases, as those are much sturdier.