Box for check-in baggage?
Hi I just want to know if it is allowed in china southern to use box as check-in baggage?

What does the China Southern website say? Most airlines just give size and weight restrictions, although its also implicit that the baggage must be securely packed (so not a paper bag).

Make sure the string etc. wrapping is strong enough for the baggage crew to use as a handle.

Many airlines will not accept cardboard boxes, because they are too fragile, especially if they get wet. They are also often easily torn, pierced, squashed, etc.

It's pretty common to see commercial shipping cartons on baggage belts in Asia. If your box is not up to commercial standards and you can't tape it up yourself in time you can get it wrapped (for a price) at most airports. I suggest bringing a roll of tape since security may require it to be opened (has happened to me - they called me to the inspection station for checked bags).

The "Ocean Jumping Bags" plus a little parcel tape mentioned in my SE Travel answer here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/23075/3301will convert a marginal box to something suitable.

You can read China Southern luggage policy here: https://www.csair.com/us/en/orders/order/kpxlgd/
Specifically

Checked baggage must be well-packaged, securely locked, firmly tied, able to withstand a certain amount of pressure, and capable of being safely handled and transported under normal operating conditions.

and

China Southern may refuse to accept and transport any baggage whose packing does not meet the requirements.

Typically a sturdy carton that's within the size and weight limits, and that's well taped, padded and/or wrapped will be accepted. The airline might make you sign a "liability waiver", i.e. if the box gets damaged you are not entitled to any sort of compensation.
Keep in mind, that checked luggage gets handled quite roughly. It gets thrown around a lot and quite a bit of weight might be stacked on top of it. It is in your own best interest to use good packaging materials especially if there is anything in the box that can break.

Thank you so much. Their rules felt a bit different for me since when traveling with previous airlines they don’t care about the size and the quantity of luggage we will bring as long as the weight is within the limit.

@RoshanneAyson: " with previous airlines they don’t care about the size and the quantity of luggage"  Unlikely. Airlines care very much about size and quantity since baggage fees are a major source of revenue for them. I suggest reading the baggage rules and fee schedule VERY carefully. If there is any chance for them to charge you, they will.
